# how to pid of Child process, generated from some script

Tags: linux

I am running a script like

```
myparent ../file&
```

it generates another process, let say, child, how I can grep this PID of child.

my script is like,

```
myparent ../file&
set PD=$!
echo "PD"
```

but it gives the PID of myparent command, not child one

Comment: Only if `myparrent` puts the PID somewhere that the original script can read it.

Comment: I think you mean `echo $PD` at the end.

Comment: If you would show the code of `myparent` in your question it would be easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: for example, I am running a simulation, %simulator_exectable ../input/file& this generate a process say "simulation", I want to find PID of this